# Powershell Remoting Handover Variables

Tags: powershell, remoting

I've opened a Remote Session s1, and like to run a function with Parameters i handover in my scriptblock:

Simplified example with Write-Host:

```
$a = "aaa"
$b = "bbb"
$c = "ccc"
$d = "ddd"
Write-Host "AAAAA: $a $b $c $d"  #This works fine as it's locally


Invoke-Command -Session $s1 -scriptblock {Write-Host "BBBBB: $a $b $c $d"}  #These variables are empty
```

What is the cleanest way to handover Variables (I normally receive from a local csv file) to the scriptblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "pass" the parameters into your script block using the `ArgumentList` parameter on `Invoke-Command`. This should do it for you:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s1 -scriptblock {param($a, $b, $c, $d) Write-Host "BBBBB: $a $b $c $d"} -ArgumentList $a, $b, $c, $d
```

Comment: Thanks, Already played with param but i was missing the
 -ArgumentList